# iCloud notes not syncing on iOS 8 on iPhone 6, but syncing on iOS 12 and iOS 15

Tags: ios, icloud, notes.app

I have 3 iPhones - iP 13 with iOS 15, iP 6 with iOS 12, iP 6 with iOS 8.1.2 (jailbroken).

All are signed into my iCloud account with Notes syncing enabled.

I can see my iCloud notes only on my iOS 15 and iOS 12.

As for iOS 8.1.2, there are no notes here under the iCloud section. Wifi and mobile data are enabled.

I have this device jailbroken, so I hesitate to upgrade it and lose that functionality.

*Without updating the OS*, what could be the reason, and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, it's because the OS is too old to understand the current two-factor authentication methods.
You can update the 6 to iOS 12, which is new enough to understand.

I just tested my old 5S & once I'd signed into iCloud again [with 2FA] then the Notes synced immediately.

On older Macs I've seen it's possible to get around this by entering your password followed by the authentication code, eg myPass123456. I don't know if this would also work for iOS.

*Late edit*
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notes_(Apple) says there was a format change at iOS 9 which will explain it not working for iOS 8

Comment: Is there any other way to solve other than update? I have not been willing to update this phone bec of the jailbreak, and I am keeping the OS for use of old apps

Comment: You can try the password hack, but there's no other way if it can't recognise 2FA. Depending on the age of your macOS [I think up to High Sierra can do this] You can get an older version of iTunes which will still sync your apps back to the Mac, thereby enabling you to reload ones no longer on the Store via Configurator. [I have no clue how or if this works with a jailbreak, it's not something I've ever needed.]

Comment: Does iCloud work otherwise? I'm not sure if 2FA is actually the problem, rather than the old Notes app not being compatible to a newer Notes database.

Comment: Not sure about differing iOS versions, but I remember that Notes.app or was it Reminder.app(?) on macOS Mojave would not sync with iCloud without upgrading to Big Sur/Catalina. So it could be something similar like that for iOS 8?

Comment: @AVelj - might be Reminders, which I never use. Notes still syncs fine from Mojave to iOS 15 & back. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notes_(Apple) says there was a format change at iOS 9 which will explain it not working for iOS 8.

Comment: @Tetsujin ah yes, it was Reminders that wasn't syncing with old macOS versions and something to do with upgraded reminders app in iOS 14.